# Extract specific number from tuple value in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have this tuple:

```
q =({'sum(total)': Decimal('89')},)
```

I need to extract the number from it in a separate variable. I tried

```
(x1,x2) = q
```

but this raises an error:

```
E       ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am not familiar with tuples and have no more ideas how I can extract it.

Comment: You don't have any integers in your object. You have a `decimal.Decimal()` object, which models a [Real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tuple contains only **one** element, a dictionary, with one key-value pair. If you wanted to extract that pair, you'd need to address it:

```
(x1, x2), = q[0].items()
```

The above expression extracts the first element from the tuple (the dictionary), and calls the `dict.items()` method on that. The resulting sequence of `(key, value)` pairs is then assigned to the `(key, value),` left-hand target, which can only take *one* such pair.

Demo:

```
>>> q = ({'sum(total)': Decimal('89')},)
>>> (x1, x2), = q[0].items()
>>> x1
'sum(total)'
>>> x2
Decimal('89')
```

You could also just iterate over all key-value pairs in the tuple, or you could use the key name. The latter, for example, would look like this:

```
decimal_value = q[0]['sum(total)']
```

You can still use unpacking in the assignment of course:

```
contained_dictionary, = q
decimal_value = contained_dictionary['sum(total)']
```

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve, and if the dictionary has different keys or should only ever contain *one* key-value pair.